# How to solve keyboard crashes?

Tags: codenameone

I realized a program under codenameone and it worked very well; but since this morning I observe a bizzare behavior of my program that I newly compiled for android. Indeed on the identification's form for example, when I put the focus on the Login field and that I return on the PASSWORD field, the keyboard crashes and the text typed is confused with the text in Hint

Is this a compilation error? what is it, how to correct it.
Thanks

Comment: It's not a compilation error if you can actually compile it?

Comment: I compile, but the problem persists. Even compiling earlier versions of my program is producing the same error now

Comment: Still having problem

Comment: I think the problem comes from the codenameone build server, since my old program also has the same problem with the compilation

Comment: Can you provide a sample of this? On which device type is this happening iOS/Android? What specific vendor/model? Which OS version?

Comment: I'm using Android devices (Android 5 and 6) Program is realized on Windows 8 PC with Netbeans 8

Comment: When moving from one input field to another, the keyboard crashes and the text typed is confused with the Hint text that does not disappear on focus

Comment: emailInput = new TextField();
        emailInput.setConstraint(TextField.EMAILADDR);
        emailInput.setHint("Email");
        emailInput.setUIID("SignInField");
        emailInput.getHintLabel().setUIID("SignInHint");
        pwdInput = new TextField();
        pwdInput.setConstraint(TextField.PASSWORD);
        pwdInput.setHint("Enter Password");
        pwdInput.setUIID("SignInField");
        pwdInput.getHintLabel().setUIID("SignInHint");

Comment: What I also noticed is that the virtual keyboard disappears and reappears when passing the focus' one input field to another

Comment: Is there any solution for my query?

Comment: We made a hotfix to see if this issue might relate to something we did. Please try sending a new build and see if the problem is still happening. If it is a video/screenshots would help

Comment: It is ok. Thanks for the hotfix